# IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found - Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have to build a Spring Batch system. In my project I have to call, inside a batch scheduled, an Api method defined in Controller class of my project.
This is an example of controller

```
@RestController
public class MyController implements ExampleApi {
// other methods

    @Override
    public ResponseEntity<ExampleResponse> method(String object){
        final ExampleResponse response = // execution
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.OK).body(response);
    }
}
```

I call the method above in my CustomProcessor. This is an example of Batch processor

```
public class CustomProcessor implements ItemProcessor<List<String>, List<String>> {

    @Autowired
    private ExampleApi exampleApi;

    @Override
    public List<String> process(@NonNull List<String> objects) throws Exception {
       
        objects.forEach(object -> exampleApi.method(object));

        return objects;
    }
}
```

When batch starts running I can call the api, but when I call inside another api in another class annotated like this:

```
@Component
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
public class ObjectFactoryImpl implements ObjectFactory {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("anotherService")
    private ObjectProvider<AnotherApi> anotherApiObjectProvider;

    public Object find(Long objectId) {
      Object object;
      try {
        object = anotherApiObjectProvider.getObject().getObjectById(objectId).getObject();
      } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Exception....
    }
}
```

I get this exception:

> IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you
> referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or
> processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If
> you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this
> message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet:
> In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to
> expose the current request.

I'm quite new to Spring Batch.

Comment: The error message simply states that you are using request parameter outside the request context. From your example, I am not able to figure out what exactly you are trying to do.

Comment: Why is your code calling a rest controller? Rest controllers are for offering HTTP APIs to clients, not for calling it within your own code.